# Suggest me 3m Micro to A-Type USB and Type-C to A-Type USB cable with not less than USB 3 and with not less than 2A support

Tags: usb, cable

Suggest me 3m Micro to A-Type USB and Type-C to A-Type USB cable with not less than USB 3 with not less than 2A support. I tried to find these but didn't find anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Micro B (3.0) <-> A

Though I cannot personally vouch for the integrity of any of these cables, [StarTech](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S2N2L5E), [C2G](https://www.cablestogo.com/product/54176/1m-usb-3.0-a-male-to-micro-b-male-cable-3.3ft), [Cable Matters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C7T78H0), and [Tripp-Lite](https://www.cdw.com/product/tripp-lite-10ft-usb-3.0-superspeed-device-cable-a-male-to-micro-b-male-10ft/2157135) are all fairly reputable manufactures who produce cables that fit your description.

## Micro B (3.0) <-> C

There are no cables of this length that I would be comfortable recommending. Per the @USBCGuy spreadsheet, the only cable in this category I'd be comfortable recommending is this [AmazonBasics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GGKYJG8) 0.9m one, which otherwise meets your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, but I thought Micro B is like [this](https://www.avitela.lt/media/catalog/product/cache/207e23213cf636ccdef205098cf3c8a3/4/7/47917_1.jpg), not like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi04u7ZnYPnAhW9zcQBHQGPBrgQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.topocentras.lt%2Fkabelis-deltaco-usb-3-0-a-micro-b-0-5m-melynas-usb3-005-k.html&psig=AOvVaw05voi9KTthHfn7ZU0yxXeq&ust=1579096127795842)

Comment: @vasik988 Then you have conflicting requirements. The smaller Micro B connector is USB 2.0 only; the extension-y bit on the larger connector has the extra data pins needed for USB 3.0.